# Simple Dump of Variable Contents

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I can successfully execute a query on a mySQL database and assign the output to a variable using the following line:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from test");
```

How can i dump the contents of the variable $result without using an array and a while loop?

I have tried:
print_r($result),
print ($result),
print $result,
echo $result

Comment: `->fetch_assoc`, if there are more rows, you will need a loop.

Comment: `without using an array and a while loop` - why don't you want to use a loop and array?

Comment: because i find it more difficult to use an array and loop and at this point it would be sufficient for me to dump the contents of the variable to confirm the query is returning what I expect.

Comment: It is only 3 lines, and you can literally just copy paste our answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop and [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php):

```
/* fetch associative array */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

If you want, you can make this a function, put it in your code, and simply call it:

```
function dumpQuery($result) {
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        print_r($row);
    }
}

...

$result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from test");
dumpQuery($result);
```

Comment: the question said without using loops :)

Comment: That is correct @DevZer0 "without loops".  What I wanted was a quick and dirty first check.  I had hoped there was a function (that I did not yet know about) that would just dump the contents of the variable, if that was correct, then I could proceed further.  What I am hearing contributers say is that there is no such function.

Comment: Unless you have `mysqlnd` for `mysqli_fetch_all()`, you can define a function for convenience and use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query= mysqli_query($con,"select * from test");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
  print_r($row);
}
```

Didn't test it because I'm not in front of the computer, but I think this is what you need.